# Reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a question.
I have partition for home with directory "abc". So /home/abc
If I will reinstall Ubuntu and create the same user "abc" my data will be OK? Will this folder be cleared and created again?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com since it's not programming related (will probably soon be migrated over there, you can follow your question by clicking on the provided link).

Comment: I think you should ask this on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: Just closing as off-topic since the answer is already on AskUbuntu.com.

Answer (score 2):

https://askubuntu.com/search?q=reinstall+home

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  @bobince, if it is a SEPARATE partition, no problem.  If you are trying to install over that partition it is going to get wiped.

Comment: It's on a separate partition, and won't be affected by reinstalling Ubuntu on the system partition .